# GET http://quiz.localhost/null 404 (Not Found)

Tags: laravel

I have a homepage with its URL is "quiz.localhost". Every others URL working fine such as "quiz.localhost/profile", "quiz.localhost/admin",...

But when I go to the homepage, i got this error although everything at the homepage is still working fine. I dont know why

> GET http://quiz.localhost/null 404 (Not Found)

This is my .env file

```
CONFIG_BASE_URL=http://quiz.localhost
```

This is my Route:

```
Route::get('/', 'PageController@getHome');
Route::get('home', 'PageController@getHome');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your routes you defined that homepage are on routes:
 http://quiz.localhost and
 http://quiz.localhost/home

route  http://quiz.localhost/null is none of those.
null here is just url paramether like /admin, /profile etc...
It can be that you have some function that redirect you to /null when you try to go to your homepage.

Hope it helps !